# How to specify the home directory for the base tag?

Tags: html

For my front end modules I want to be able to load them in the browse directly.  So I need my base tag to recognize the home directory but it does not.  Is there a way to specify home directory in the path.

Below does not work as the tilde is not interpreted.

```
<base href="~/root/web/source/" target="_blank">
```

If I use

```
<base href="/web/source/" target="_blank">
```

It works for the server but not on my client as there are different evaluations for the leading `/` ( root ).

Similar results for:

```
<base href="web/source/" target="_blank">
```

Oddly, the server interprets a preceding forward slash the same as no forward preceding slash.

The client interprests the relative path as:

```
/Users/a/root/web/source/htm
```

While the server interprets the relative path as ( the public_html directory )

```
/root
```

which are very different.

Comment: have you tried `./` instead of `~/`? the dot means the current directory, a tilde usually means the home directory, but isn't valid in a browser while the dot is valid in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using `./` at the beginning of the path (which as I explained will interpret the relative path relative to the **current** location whereas omitting the dot will interpret the path relative to the base url) would be to use some javascript to determine the correct path based on the provided substring:

```
// will set the <base> path automatically 
// as whatever path ""web/source/" is located in
(function(relativePath){
    var baseElement = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
    var url = ""+window.location;
    var basepath = url.substr(0, url.indexOf(relativePath));
    baseElement.href = basepath+relativePath;
})("web/source/");
```

Obviously, that needs to go in script tags.

Comment: Ended up using JS - window.location.origin - and creating the base tag in the JS.